# Replace negative values in dataframe by NaN, replace NaN with fillna method

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to replace negative entries in the column of a dataframe. 
I am setting the values to NaN and then apply the fillna method.

A section of the dataframe containing a negative entry looks like this

```
print df_sel.P_L_Bef_2.loc[67141:67143]

67141    96745
67142   -20625
67143    96745
Name: P_L_Bef_2, dtype: float64
```

This next part is where I suspect the error. Although I have read a couple of issues about assigning to a copy instead of view, I thought that using .loc might take care of that.

```
df_sel.loc[df_sel.P_L_Bef_2 < 0] = np.nan
print df_sel.P_L_Bef_2.loc[67141:67143]

67141    96745
67142      NaN
67143    96745
Name: P_L_Bef_2, dtype: float64
```

So far so good. Maybe! But ...

```
df_sel['P_L_Bef_2'].fillna(method='ffill')
print df_sel.P_L_Bef_2.loc[67141:67143]

67141    96745
67142      NaN
67143    96745
Name: P_L_Bef_2, dtype: float64
```

So, am I still assigning to a copy or is the fillna method working other than I am expecting?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see a difference because by default it doesn't perform this inplace so you need to assign the result:

```
df_sel['P_L_Bef_2'] = df_sel['P_L_Bef_2'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

or set `inplace = True`, the docs for [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas.Series.fillna) show what args it takes and the default param values. So setting `inplace = True` should work too:

```
df_sel['P_L_Bef_2'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```